# How do I import blogs?

Tags: 7, nodes

How can I import blogs that were created in a Drupal 6 site to a Drupal 7 site? I'm not looking to upgrade the Drupal 6 site because the Drupal 7 site is a complete redesign of the old one and I wanted a clean start. I would like to not have to manually copy all of the blogs to the new site.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the excellent [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module for this. Another quick way to do this, is using the [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module, which lets you import data using RSS and a variety of other formats.

Comment: How exactly do you use the Migrate module?

Comment: It depends on what version you're using. The version I've used had a GUI and there was a nice Lullabot tutorial for it: http://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-data-imports-migrate-and-table-wizard - For the new version you need to write some code, I found a series of tutorials: http://btmash.com/article/2011-02-25/migrating-content-using-migrate-module - You can always have a look at the docs: http://drupal.org/node/415260